# Meteor + FineUploader + s3

Tags: meteor, fine-uploader

Right now I'm using the CLIENT ONLY implementation of FineUploader in my meteor app.  With how tightly Meteor is coupled with the server, it doesn't make sense to add this layer of complexity.  What also doesn't make sense to me is how to go about this properly.

The FineUploader code is documented - you set an endpoint.

There are packages like https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/s3policies, but they don't work with endpoints (as far as I can tell).

There is the nodejs server example, but I haven't a clue how to use it as part of my meteor project.

What is a working way to call a method on the server,

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
      's3policy': function(options) {
          // use something like https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/s3policies
          // or something like https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/nodejs/s3/s3handler.js
      }
  });
}
```

From the client and use it in the uploader

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    signature: {
        endpoint: '/s3/signature'
        // with the server side code from
        // https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/nodejs/s3/s3handler.js
        // but this seems like it bypasses meteor's awesome
        // and I don't know how to go about it
        endpoint: Meteor.call('s3policy', {});
        // this makes more sense to me but I'm not knowledgable enough
        // about both technologies to make this work
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see a question. What _specific_ problem are you having?

Comment: The specific struggles I have are 2 fold: first, is it better to try and create a url endpoint on meteor (not inherit to meteor) or to get FineUploader to accept some kind of policy generated through a function call and not a traditional endpoint.  Then, how to actually achieve it.  If I were more intelligent this would be a lot easier.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately I have zero knowledge of meteor, so I can't provide any help here. Hopefully someone with meteor experience will see this and lend a hand.

Comment: I wonder if FineUploader might be coupling the specific implementation of s3's signed policy too closely?  Maybe it shouldn't be restricted to an endpoint - but actually accept the signed policy?  That way the user could decide how they are going to go about that?  Again, I guess it's just a little outside my grasp.

Comment: Note that policies are only used for older browsers and non-chunked uploads. All other uploads take a different approach and require a string of headers to be signed due to use of the s3 multiparty upload api